# Quotient of a sheaf by group action and representabillity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, group-schemes, representable-functors

Let $X$ be a scheme and $S$ be a sheaf of sets over the fppf topology of $X$. Let $G$ be a group scheme over $X$ and there is an action of $G$ on $S$. Now, I want to look at the quotient $G \setminus S$. The way I want to define quotient is $ (G\setminus S)(U) = G(U) \setminus S(U)
$? Is it necessary that $(G\setminus S)$ is a sheaf? To define $(G\setminus S)$  is necessary to do specification?

Now, suppose $(G\setminus S)$ is representable. Does that imply $S$ is representable?

Comment: There are cases where the quotient presheaf of $S$ by $G$ is a representable sheaf, yet $S$ is not representable.  For instance, let $G_0$ be a nontrivial finite group, let $X$ equal $\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{C}[[t]]$ with its closed point $0:\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{C}\to X$, and let $S$ be the fppf sheaf on the category of $X$-schemes associating to every $X$-scheme $Y$ the set of locally constant functions from the closed fiber $Y_0$ to $G_0$.  Let $G$ be the constant 'etale group $X$-scheme with $G(X)=G_0$.  For the natural action of $G$ on $S$, the quotient is $X$.  Yet $S$ is not representable.